# Should Expanding a function result in changes to its Plot?

Tags: plotting, code-review

(Title needs improving)

I'm trying to find the analytical expression for the attenuation of an AC voltage through a [passive low-pass filter](https://tinyurl.com/yeoqc4ld).  The solution involves finding the time-dependent charge (`q[t]`) for the circuit and then calculating the voltage drop across the capacitor (`q[t]/c`). The equation is easy enough to solve (by Mathematica, not me).

```
Clear[q]
q[t_] := Evaluate[q[t] /. First@
   DSolve[{v Sin[2 Pi f t] - q'[t] r - q[t]/c == 0, q[0] == 0}, 
      q[t], t]]
fp = {v -> 1, f -> 40., r -> 10000, c -> 10^-6};
```

The rules `fp` are example variables for the input voltage, frequency, resistance and capacitance. Plotting the solution, we find something odd at long times.

```
Plot[q[t]/c /. fp, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

...which goes away if we `Expand`:

```
Plot[Expand[q[t]]/c /. fp, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comparing the "original" and expanded forms of the expression, we see that Mathematica is dealing with multiplying very large and small exponentials which, upon inspection, should cancel out.

```
q[t]/c
Expand[q[t]/c]
```

[image]

**Is this behavior a bug or is it inherent to math on a finite-precision device and therefore the user must be aware of the potential pitfall?**

To solve my problem, I am actually interested in the amplitude of the resulting signal, which we can obtain from the coefficients of the *sin* and *cos* terms.  **Is there a convenient way to obtain these values?**  Right now, what I'm doing is a bit clumsy (but works).

```
Rest@Level[Expand[q[t]/c], {1}] /. {Cos[_] :> 1, Sin[_] :> 1}
Simplify[Sqrt@Total[#^2 & /@ %]/v, v > 0]
```

[image]

It does not appear that there is a built in method for obtaining coefficients from a user defined series  (e.g. `CustomCoefficients[<expr>, <pattern>]`)

Comment: One of the first things I do is replace `Plot` by `Table`: Try `Table[q[t]/c /. fp, {t, 0., 10.}]` -- important: Use machine precision in `Table`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That does reveal the problem right away.

Comment: Just generally, on the title, and your suspicions about numerical precision, the answer is yes - differently expanded forms of the same expression can lead to better or worse precision. There are tools to find more accurate floating point expressions such as [herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org) which may be useful if you can convert your expression to C/C++/FORTRAN.

Comment: @flinty in this case, I am not concerned about precision, but rather the fact that the solution provided by `DSolve` is in a form that leads to precision errors unnecessarily.  Is there any software design philosophy that would justify why Wolfram doesn't effectively apply `Simplify` to their core functions?